# Normal parametrization of a line for the Hough Transform. How is $\theta$ defined for a line through the origin

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, parametrization

For a straighline in 2D space $y=mx+b$, the normal parametrization of the line gives an alternate representation of the line as $R=x\cos\theta  +y\sin\theta$, where $R$ is the algebraic distance from the origin to the line and  $\theta$ is the angle $R$ makes with the line.

In the paper [Use of the Hough Transform to Detect Lines and Curves](http://www.ai.sri.com/pubs/files/tn036-duda71.pdf), the author states that restricting  $\theta$ to $[0,\pi)$ gives a unique representation of all possible lines.

My question is how would $\theta$ be defined for lines passing through the origin such that they are also uniquely identified by $R$ and $\theta$ ?

PS: Also I am pretty sure that $R$ is allowed to be negative in this definition but would be nice if anyone could confirm this ?

Comment: If R is the "geometric distance" from the origin to the line, it cannot be negative. Also do you mean those o's in coso etc to be thetas?

Comment: @coffeemath Yes I meant for the 0's to be thetas but did not know how to write that. And R is the algebraic distance. My mistake

Comment: @coffeemath I updated the question with the correct Tex notation to make it clearer

Comment: @acevans Acevans, the distance is 'geometric', it is always positive in Hough method, you have been right.

Comment: @Widawensen But it states algebraic distance in the paper that I linked to. 5th page of the pdf which is the 2nd page of the paper presented. Also it makes more sense as lines that have a negative y-intercept could otherwise not be represented.

Comment: @acevans  Maybe this because of restriction of $\theta$ in his paper.

Comment: @Widawensen Yeah I thought so too. But the real question is how is $\theta$ defined for lines through the origin ? Would it be with their slope $ \tan \theta $ ?

Comment: @acevans Generally the $\theta$ in Hough method is the angle between normal to the line and axis $Ox$

Comment: @acevans It's also coherent with presentation Hough method in wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform